# Dynamically calculating total for each column based on selected rows for HTML table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, calculated-columns

[image: html table]

From the picture, I am trying to calculate the total of each column for the selected rows a and c.  The code works if I unwrap it from the function calculateCols.  Is it possible to make it work in the wrapped function.  I want to be able to choose a variation of rows to sum for each column without copy and pasting the code and editing it multiple times for each one.

```js
function calculateCols(ID, calculate) {
  var final = 0
  var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
  var howManyCols = tbody.rows[0].cells.length;
  var totalRow = document.getElementById(ID);

  for (var j = 1; j < howManyCols; j++) {
    final = calculate;
    const check = document.createElement('td');
    check.innerText = final;
    totalRow.appendChild(check);
  }

  function getRow(rowID) {

    var result = 0;

    try {
      var check = document.getElementById(rowID)
      var thisNumber = parseInt(check.cells[j].childNodes.item(0).data);

      if (!isNaN(thisNumber))
        result += thisNumber;

    } finally {
      return result;
    }
  }

}

calculateCols('total', getRow('a') + getRow('c'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th scope="col">2013</th>
        <th scope="col">2014</th>
        <th scope="col">2015</th>
        <th scope="col">2016</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="a">
        <th scope="row">a</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="b">
        <th scope="row">b</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="c">
        <th scope="row">c</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="d">
        <th scope="row">d</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="total">
        <th scope="row" id="Total">Total a + c</th>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="checkit.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this easily using the [:nth-child(2n+1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) css selector with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to sum the selections.  I've done this with very large complex tables and it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
function rpn(inps, D, i) { // Reverse Polish Notation calculator
  const st = [];
  inps.split(/\s+/).forEach(t => {
    let k = st.length - 2; // index of penultimate element on stack
    if (!isNaN(t)) st.push(+t);
    else switch (t) {
      case "+": st[k] += st.pop(); break;
      case "-": st[k] -= st.pop(); break;
      case "*": st[k] *= st.pop(); break;
      case "/": st[k] /= st.pop(); break;
      case "**": st[k] = st[k] ** st.pop(); break;
      default: st.push(+D[t][i]) // treat current value t as a "variable name" --> D[t][i]
    }
  });
  return st.pop()
}
// sample use (Pythagoras's theorem): rpn("3 2 ** 4 2 ** + .5 **") // = 5

// get all table data into D first:
  const D = [...document.querySelectorAll("tr[id]")].reduce((da, tr) => {
      da[tr.id] = [...tr.children].slice(1).map(td => +td.textContent);
      return da;
    }, {});
  document.querySelectorAll("tr[data-eqn]").forEach(tr =>
    [...tr.children].slice(1).forEach((td,k)=>
      td.textContent=rpn(tr.dataset.eqn, D, k).toFixed(4).replace(/\.?0*$/,"")));
```

```css
td,th {text-align: right; padding:4px}
td    {border:1px solid grey}
table {border-collapse:collapse}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th scope="col">2013</th>
      <th scope="col">2014</th>
      <th scope="col">2015</th>
      <th scope="col">2016</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="a">
      <th scope="row">a</th>
      <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="b">
      <th scope="row">b</th>
      <td>5</td><td>6</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-eqn="a 2 ** b 2 ** + .5 **">
      <th scope="row">sqrt(a²+b²)</th>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="c">
      <th scope="row">c</th>
      <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="d">
      <th scope="row">d</th>
      <td>5</td><td>6</td><td>8</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-eqn="2 a * d + c -">
      <th scope="row">2a + d - c</th>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-eqn="a b - a b + / c *">
      <th scope="row">(a - b) / (a + b) * c</th>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-eqn="b c /">
      <th scope="row">b/c</th>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-eqn="a b +">
      <th scope="row">a + b</th>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-eqn="c b +">
      <th scope="row">c + b</th>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I changed my answer completely again: The centre piece of the operation is now an RPN calculator (function `rpn()`) that goes through instructions strings provided by `data-eqn` attributes in all so identified result-`<tr>`s.

Before the calculation can start I collect all provided table data in a global object `D`. All `tr`s with an `id`-attribute contribute their `td.textContent` to a vector which becomes property `D[id]`. `D` ends up being an object of arrays.

[[ Currently the results are limited to 3 digits. This can easily be switched off by removing `.toFixed(3)` again. ]]

Comment: what if I want to +, -, /, * for each columns the selected rows e.g. a + d - c, or (a + b) * c, or b/c, etc. I would like to try many variations and populating them to different rows not just the last row.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now you can specify arbitrary row IDs to be summed up into a results-row that you can also specify in terms of its ID. I just realised that you want even more: arbitrary operations, specified in terms of an equation given in the first column. That should also be possible. Give me a few minutes more ;-)

Comment: After a good night's sleep I came back to my answer and rewrote it completely. Now you can enter as many equations in "reverse Polish notation" as you like. Their results will be calculated and displayed in that row's columns.

Comment: @iuol, have you checked out my answer?

Comment: yes I did. thanks.  but I can't seem to get the + working on itself.  e.g. a + b, c + b.

Comment: [RPN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) means that you need to put the operators _after_ the two operands, so "a b +" is the RPN way of doing `a+b`. I just added two more rows with your expressions to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shuffled the scopes (help: https://davidwalsh.name/for-and-against-let).
E.g.`check.cells[j]` always return `howManyCols-1`.
The first mistake (the debugger also warns), the `getRow` function is within the `calculateCols` function, but the call (`calculateCols('total',getRow('a'),getRow('c'))`) is not.

I have written a simpler code.

```js
let results = {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d: 0};
rows = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll('#'+rows[i]+' td').forEach(
    function(elem) {
      results[rows[i]] += Number(elem.textContent)
    }
  )
}
for (let i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
  let result = document.createElement('td');
  result.textContent = results[rows[i]];
  document.querySelector('#total').appendChild(result);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th scope="col">2013</th>
        <th scope="col">2014</th>
        <th scope="col">2015</th>
        <th scope="col">2016</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="a">
        <th scope="row">a</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="b">
        <th scope="row">b</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="c">
        <th scope="row">c</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="d">
        <th scope="row">d</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="total">
        <th scope="row" id="Total">Total</th>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="checkit.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

If you want to only get the `a` and `c` rows' amount, set the list `rows` `['a','c']`

Comment: I am trying to calculate the row a + c for each column.
Total a + c 5, 7, 9, 11.  But not necessarily just for a+c.  It would be helpful if it can be for multiple rows.  e.g a+b+c, or a+d. etc.

Comment: @iuol The `rows` list contains the id of rows to add (for example, if  you want to get a+c+d, set `rows=['a','c','d']`)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th scope="col">2013</th>
        <th scope="col">2014</th>
        <th scope="col">2015</th>
        <th scope="col">2016</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="a">
        <th scope="row">a</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="b">
        <th scope="row">b</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="c">
        <th scope="row">c</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="d">
        <th scope="row">d</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="total">
        <th scope="row" id="Total"></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    function toIntOrZero(value) {
      let toInt = parseInt(value);
      return !isNaN(toInt) ? toInt : 0;
    }

    function getRowValues(rowID) {
      let children = document.getElementById(rowID).children;
      let values = [];
      for (let i = 1; i < children.length; i++) {
        values.push(toIntOrZero(children[i].innerText));
      }
      return values;
    }

    function getRows(rowIds) {
      return rowIds.map(id => getRowValues(id));
    }

    function calculateColSums(array) {
      return array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (b, i) {
          r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b;
        });
        return r;
      }, []);
    }

    function appendResults(results, rowIds) {
      document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML = 'Total of ' + rowIds.join();
      var tableTotalRow = document.querySelector('tbody > #total');
      var totalColumns = document.querySelector('tbody').rows[0].cells.length;
      for (var j = 1; j < totalColumns; j++) {
        const colSum = document.createElement('td');
        colSum.innerText = results[j - 1];
        tableTotalRow.appendChild(colSum);
      }
    }

    function calculateSumOfSelectedRows(rowIds) {
      appendResults(calculateColSums(getRows(rowIds)), rowIds);
    }

    calculateSumOfSelectedRows(['b', 'd']);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```